# What is the command to assign different colors to reviewers in ShareLaTeX so that their comments can be seen in different color?

Tags: comments, todonotes

Let's say there are few reviewers and they want to comment on different sections of your paper in ShareLaTeX. I am not talking about the default commenting method.

I want to use this method, this is one way of commenting:

```
\newcommand{\ps}[1]
{\stepcounter{todocounter}
 \todo[color=green!40,author=Peter, inline]{\thetodocounter: #1}
 }
```

and let's say Peter commented this (`\ps{Hello there!}`) on the top of paragraph 2 in the paper. This is how the comment appears in the paper:

[image: This is how the comment appears in the paper]

Till now it works fine, now further I want the same reviewer to review but it has to appear differently. Now instead of appearing in a boxlike structure outside the paragraph, I want the comment to appear inside the paragraph, like this (the text in green is the comment)

[image: Image of how the second type of review written by the same person should appear in the paper]

But, it does not seem to work. This is what I have tried, but does not seem to work.

```
\newcommand{\ps}[1]
{\stepcounter{todocounter} \texthl{#1}
 \todo[color=green!40,author=Peter]{\thetodocounter: #1}
 }
```

How should I change it so that the review appears as I stated above?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need a todo-list, you could simply do something like the `\peter` command here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcounter{todocounter}
\newcommand{\ps}[1]
{\stepcounter{todocounter}
 \todo[color=green!40,author=Peter, inline]{\thetodocounter: #1}
 }

\newcommand{\peter}[1]{\stepcounter{todocounter}
  {\color{green!90} Peter: \thetodocounter: #1}}

\begin{document}    
First method\ps{Next time please add a complete MWE!}

Second method\peter{Something like this?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can add as many commands you need, one per author, or you can even create a unique command, with the author as one of the parameters, which changes color according to the author.

I think it also possible to add them to the todo list, please let me know if this answer is enough or you need other features.

Next time, don't forget to add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)!